# Elastic search using NEST with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, elasticsearch, nest

I have an sql table with columns Name, Category, Location. I am using Elastic Search with [NEST](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/). my query like this:

```
var result = client.Search<Models.Search.Poll>(s => s.Query(q => q.Fuzzy(f => f.OnField(p => p.Name).Value(query))))));
```

So if there is a record with name = "We are here" and user search "are" , it returns result.

Now I need to add two more parameters category and location to this query:

so I made it like this:

```
var result = client.Search<Models.Search.Poll>(s => s.Query(q => q.Fuzzy(f => f.OnField(p => p.Name).Value(query).OnField(r => r.Category).Value(category))));
```

but it is not working with query field now. but it works with category now. here is what I get when I type name but dont select category:

```
StatusCode: OK, 
    Method: POST, 
    Url: http://server.abc.com:9200/pollit-dev/polls/_search, 
    Request: {
  "query": {
    "fuzzy": {
      "category": {
        "value": "Select a Category"
      }
    }
  }
}, 
    Response: {"took":2892,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}
```

I tried this one well:

```
var result = client.Search<Models.Search.Poll>(s => s.MatchAll().Query(q => q.Term(p => p.Name, query) || q.Term(p => p.Category,category) || q.Term(p => p.Location, Location)
```

but no luck so far.

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options for that.
First one is almost like yours but you have to use a Bool condition there.

```
var result = client.Search<Models.Search.Poll>(s => s
      .MatchAll()
      .Query(q => q
         .Bool(b => b
           .Must(m => m.Term(p => p.Name, query) || m.Term(p => p.Category,category) || m.Term(p => p.Location, Location))
         )
       )
   );
```

Now another option is to use queryContainers. Something like this:

```
var result = _Instance.Search<Models.Search.Poll>(q => q
                .Query(qq =>
                {
                    QueryContainer termQuery = null;
                    QueryContainer locationQuery = null;
                    QueryContainer categoryQuery = null;

                    termQuery = qq.Term(p => p.Name, query);
                    categoryQuery = qq.Term(p => p.Category,category);
                    locationQuery = qq.Term(p => p.Location, Location);

                    return termQuery || categoryQuery || locationQuery;
                    })
           );
```

You can also elaborate the QueryContainers and add multiple search parameters there.
Hope this helps you. Great day!

Comment: This only works if there is at least one exact match if I am right.